# strcpy_s buffer L buffer is too small && 0

Tags: c++, strcpy

i have a problem.

i tried to proceede the following steps:

```
    char * str;
    char * s="Hello";
    int len = std::strlen(s);
        str=new char[len +10];
    strcpy_s(str,sizeof(str) ,s);
```

But the programm displays the error, which i write in the title.

If i replace the sizeof(str) with a number, for example 256, a pop up window appear with the message project.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

How can i solve this errors with strcpy_s??
Thank you!

Comment: When standard library functions don’t do what you expect, look at the arguments you’ve calling them with. Print the value os `sizeof(str)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof(str)` returns the size of `char*` which is (probably) either `4` or `8` (bytes) depending on the implementation. In your case it appears to be `4` which is not enough to hold the characters that make up the `"Hello"` literal plus the null terminating character. Since there is not enough space the [strcpy_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) function invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).  You need at least `6` bytes which is the number of characters + `1` byte for a null character. Also instead of `str=new char[len + 10];` you probably meant `str = new char[len + 1];` to accommodate for the `\0` character. Hence your code should be:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    char* str;
    char* s = "Hello";
    int len = std::strlen(s);
    str = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy_s(str, len + 1, s);
}
```

That being said prefer [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to C-style character array.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(str)` gives the size of `char*`, which is *not* the length of the allocated array. To fix this, you must give the allocated length. In this case this would be

```
strcpy_s(str, len + 10, s);
```

Comment: Can you please explain, why i have to write len + 10? I thought i have to make only len + 1, because of the '\0' for the end ?

Comment: Because the second argument should be the size of the destination buffer. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy for more details.

Comment: In the example, which is in the source, i see the following code part:               
    char dst[strlen(src) + 1]; // +1 to accomodate for the null terminator, so why i have to make len +10 instead of len +1? And do i have allways to make len +10? I would be very thankful for a instruction!

Comment: I have taken the 10 from your question, where you allocate `new char[len + 10];`. You are correct, that `len + 1` is sufficient.